# Why are Points not Generated on the Mesh Surface?

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I properly instantiate objects onto the surface of the mesh? I just started to do a blender youtube tutorial but when I try to recreate a geometry node the objects that I want to appear on the mesh are not connected to it. I tried to apply the scale on both the icing and the sprinkle but this doesn't solve the problem.

[image]

Comment: Hello, can you kindly attach the whole geo nodes setup? (Especially the object info node)

Comment: Did you try right-clicking on the sprinkle and choosing Set Origin > Origin to Geometry?

Answer (score 0):

### Make sure you apply the position and scale of your sprinkle object & donut object.

(The sprinkle instance, not all of the sprinkles.)

To do this, select the object, press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and choose *Location*. Do it again and choose *Scale*.

If that doesn't work, try right-clicking on the sprinkle and choosing *Set Origin > Origin to Geometry.*

Comment: I'm quite sure the problem is the origin. Since the _Object Info_ node ist set to _Original_ instead of _Relative_, applying location, rotation or scale shouldn't be necessary. Actually I think applying location would rather cause trouble then help here, since the sprinkle  objects are off the world's origin, applying the location will move the object origin away from the geometry.

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. After all I deleted the sprinkles and with the new ones I applied the scale and set origin to geometry and it worked.